# SQL Compact Edition missing from "Data sources"

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2010

On the Data Sources tab, I'm trying to create a DATASET from an existing database but SQL Compact 4.0 is not showing in the data source part of the Wizard.

How ever if i try to add a new connection on "Data Connections" on "Server Explorer" tab I do get SQL CE 4.0

I have:

1. Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Professional
2. SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 ENU CTP1
3. Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4.0

I've brosed the web, and they all say that I have to install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4.0 which I already did and didn't work, i also re-installed VS and SQL CE and it didn't work.

Help me.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5653592/908336) may help (and check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10948164/908336)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact 4.0 only appears in the tooling for Web type Projects, not desktop etc.